# What settings / statements are pushed to subscribers in transactional replication?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, transactional-replication

Version: SQL Server 2014 (Web edition)
Replication: Transactional

Are the following pushed to subscribers in transactional replication?

- SET_QUOTED_IDENTIFIER statement;
- SET ANSI_NULLS statement;
- CREATE PROCEDURE statement (we have "CREATE PROCEDURE" on publisher and "CREATE PROC" on subscriber);
- Comments.